# We are given a singular matrix A and scalar k then how to prove that $\mbox{adj}(kA)=k^{n-1}\mbox{adj}(A)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

What I have so far is

$$k A\  \mbox{adj}(kA) = \det(kA)\ I_n \implies kA\  \mbox{adj}(kA) = 0 \implies A \ \mbox{adj}(kA) = 0$$

How do I proceed from here? Thank you for your help

Comment: Please format the rest.

Comment: Hi and welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Also, For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I'm new to this, what do you mean by formatting? Why exactly isn't it phrased well?

Comment: Which is more readable? The title or the body of the question?